# Call method from parent inside helper c#

Tags: c#, forms, methods, callback

I am trying to call a method from another class, but inside that method, call a method from the first class... I can't explain better, so here's what I want to do with code...

**MyClass.cs**

```
public static void validarCampos(object sender) {
**some code here**
}

// here, a KeyDown function calls MyHelper.cs=>TextBoxKyeDown method
private void tb_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as TextBox).TextBoxKeyDown(e, this);
}
```

**MyHelper.cs**

```
public static void TextBoxKeyDown(this TextBox tb, KeyEventArgs e, Control container)
{
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.Enter:
        case Keys.Add:
            tb.ZeroFill(e);
            // I want to call MyClass.cs=>validarCampos(tb);
            // here, before it moves to next TB, because on
            // validarCampos(tb) I can tell if the next TB is
            // enabled or not, if I do not call it HERE
            // when I press ENTER or ADD, it wont move next TB
            // until I press it twice...
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            container.SelectNextControl(tb, true, true, false, true);
            break;
        case Keys.Decimal:
            if ((tb.Tag as string) == "importe")
            {
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                container.SelectNextControl(tb, true, true, false, true);
            }
            break;
        case Keys.Subtract:
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            container.SelectNextControl(tb, false, true, false, true);
            break;
    }
}
```

Really sorry for the explanation, if you need more clues tell me... I do not paste whole validarCampos code because it is ~140 lines... It just check the contents of the TextBoxes and determine which ones are enabled or disabled depending on the result...

Comment: What problem are you having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the helper method varies depending on context, then take a look at [Action delagates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx).  You could pass the function in as a parameter to TextBoxKeyDown.  I'd expect the function to look something like:

```
void TextBoxKeyDown(this TextBox tb, KeyEventArgs e, Control container, 
                    Action<object> CallBack)
{
   CallBack(tb);
}
```

and could be called with:

```
(sender as TextBox).TextBoxKeyDown(e, this, validarCampos);
```

Comment: I actually had a look to delegates before asking here, but never used them before, so I think I was doing it wrong way... because I had tons of errors on compiler

Comment: Jesus! That was easy, I don't know how I was doing it, I think I was trying to parse `Action<TextBox> AsyncCallback` what a mess.. Very thank you, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

It's a public static method, so you can call it like:

```
MyClass.validarCampos(tb);
```

Comment: Yes, but that will work if I call the helper ONLY from one class, the problem is it's a helper, so each class has it's own `validarCampos` method, with their own parameters... The only common thing is the keydown helper.